# TD element is a inline element or block level element?

Tags: html-table

TD element in table , is a block level element or inline level ?

in tr tag  , we can have multi TD element . now i have a question : td element is a inline element ? or not ?

Comment: What's your *real* question? This sounds like a question inspired by a question, e.g., not the real problem you're having...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From a style perspective, `td` is (by default) a [`table-cell`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#value-def-table-cell) element. These are more like [`inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#value-def-inline-block) than they are like [`block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#value-def-block), but they're different from both. They're their own thing.

Comment: we can set width of table when we set table-layot:fixed , how can set different width for TD tag in different TR in CSS?
without colspan or rowspan .

Comment: @user3320972: You can't. The cells in a column have the same width; you'd have to use colspan to do that. Or not use a table.

Comment: Block level elements are separated by newline, inline elements aren't.  TR elements sometimes do separate with newlines and sometimes don't, depending on the TD elements, so, I would agree -- TR and TD elements are neither block nor inline.